# Flexible mains cord for cable management

Tags: electrical

To help with cable management I want to make some custom power cables for low power devices (computer peripherals, small audio devices etc. all under 100W). The smallest flex I can find is 1mm^2 PVC and not very flexible, for example it can't easily be bundled up and cable tied to hide excessive length due to the minimum turn radius.

The cables would have a standard British fused plug on one end and a C13 or C7 connector on the other.

I see 0.75mm^2 is available, as well as braided cable with fabric covering. It seems that the regulations are now that everything must be at least 3A rated. Is that correct, can I not use 1A cable any more? I have seen 0.3mm^2 on eBay but from outside the UK.

What is the most flexible 3 core 1A+ cable I can use in the UK? Is 2182Y 0.5mm 3A suitable?

Comment: Is this mains cables behind a fused plug, or extra-low voltage cables between a DC supply and the appliance?

Comment: Mains cables behind a fused plug, C13 on the other end, or sometimes a C7.